# Guardar modelo y relaciones con MorphToMany laravel

Tags: laravel

tengo un pequeño problema, tengo este código:

```
public function servicios() : MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(
        Cup::class,
        'model',
        'model_has_servicios',
        'model_id',
        'servicio_id'
    );
}
```

En mi modelo, el cual funciona bien al guardar las relaciones; sin embargo, puede darse el caso de agregar mas servicios relacionados con el mismo modelo y cuando esto pasa me sobrescribe los servicios guardados previamente, hay laguna forma de que los agregue sin sobreescribirlos?
Este es el modelo que se relaciona:

```
class ModelHasservicios extends Model
```

{
use HasFactory;

```
public function cita()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cita::class, 'model_id', 'id');
}
```

}